# async/await whenall does return immediately

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have this "simple" test code... (Don't bother the strange use of the Class methods...)

I am trying to grasp the `Task<>` intricacies... I think I have a little understanding of `Task<>.Start()`/`Task<>.Result` pattern (maybe as it resembles more the 'old' `Thread.Start()`?) but as soon as it seems to me to grasp something (and so I throw in the `await` keyword)... then all entangles again :-(

Why my code returns immediately after the first task completes? Why it doesn't wait on the `Task.WhenAll()`?

```
static BigInteger Factorial(BigInteger factor)
{
    BigInteger factorial = 1;
    for (BigInteger i = 1; i <= factor; i++)
    {
        factorial *= i;
    }
    return factorial;
}

private class ChancesToWin
{
    private int _n, _r;

    public ChancesToWin(int n, int r)
    {
        _n = n;
        _r = r;
    }

    private Task<BigInteger> CalculateFactAsync(int value)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<BigInteger>(() => Factorial(value));
    }

    public async Task<BigInteger> getFactN()
    {
        BigInteger result = await CalculateFactAsync(_n);
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<BigInteger> getFactN_R()
    {
        BigInteger result = await CalculateFactAsync(_n - _r);
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<BigInteger> getFactR()
    {
        BigInteger result = await CalculateFactAsync(_r);
        return result;
    }

}

private async static void TaskBasedChancesToWin_UseClass()
{
    int n = 69000;
    int r = 600;

    List<Task<BigInteger>> tasks = new List<Task<BigInteger>>();

    ChancesToWin ctw = new ChancesToWin(n, r);

    tasks.Add(ctw.getFactN());
    tasks.Add(ctw.getFactN_R());
    tasks.Add(ctw.getFactR());

    // The getFactR() returns first of the other two tasks... and the code exit!
    BigInteger[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    // I don't get here !!!!
    BigInteger chances = results[0] / results[1] * results[2];

    //Debug.WriteLine(chances);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskBasedChancesToWin_UseClass();
}
```

Comment: You should not be combining `Task.Factory.StartNew<T>(` and async/await, [there are some very easy to do bugs that can happen if you do](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), you don't have one of those bugs in this program but its a really good idea to break the "StartNew habit" now instead of later. Use `Task.Run<T>(` instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint... I have read the link... But I have to understand more the async programming framework... However in simple terms I understand that for simple cases I could simply switch `Task.Factory.StartNew<T>` with `Task.Run` without too much reasoning, right?

Comment: Yep, pretty much, you only need to do `StartNew` if you are going to be choosing a non standard TaskSchedueller which 99.9% of the time you will not need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async methods run synchronously until the first await when they return control to the calling method, usually returning a task representing the rest of the asynchronous operation. `TaskBasedChancesToWin_UseClass` doesn't return a task so the caller can't wait for it to complete. That's why you shouldn't use `async void` outside of event handlers.

Since `Main` doesn't wait for the operation your application ends before the operation had a chance to complete.

You would usually wait with `await` but since you `Main` can't be an async method you can block synchronously with `Wait` on the task returned from `TaskBasedChancesToWin_UseClass`:

```
async static Task TaskBasedChancesToWin_UseClass()
{
    // ...
}

static void Main()
{
    TaskBasedChancesToWin_UseClass().Wait();
}
```

Comment: ok, that seems to make sense to me... But so: when in the "chain" do you stop marking methods async and using await?
In other words: I wouldn't have marked the TaskBasedChancesToWin_UseClass method with async, but I have had to mark it otherwise I could't have awaited the tasks (seems like dog chasing its tail ;-)

Comment: @spiderman77 optimally... you don't stop. Async works best when it's async all the way up. It works best for UI and web apps where you have a context to return to but not so well for console apps. In such cases most people block synchronously but you can also use something like `AsyncContext` by Stephen Cleary.

Comment: In my code I can't simpy add .Wait() to the TaskBasedChancesToWin_UseClass() method !!! 
operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'

Comment: @spiderman77 `TaskBasedChancesToWin_UseClass` needs to return a task.